# at least one checkbox selected Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

I am adding the following field to my form:

```
->add('interessi_profilo', 'entity', array( 
                'label' => 'Interessi (Tr)',
                'class' => 'MyProfiloBundle:TipoInteresse',
                'required'  => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded'  => true,
                'property' => 'tipo',
                'query_builder' => function(\My\ProfiloBundle\Entity\TipoInteresseRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                            ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
                },
```

I would like for the form to be sent only if at least one checkbox is selected and, if possible, have a tooltip that tells the user: `at least one option must be selected`

Comment: you have to do this in javascript

Comment: only with Javascript?

Comment: no, also you have to check from backend but you have mentioned about a tooltip.

Comment: without tooltip but with a normal control?? I tried with NotBlank,NotNull,Valid...but the form is submitted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try putting the [`Count` constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Count.html) on the field holding the collection:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Count;

class Entity 
{
    /**
     * @Count(min = 1, minMessage = "At least one item must be selected")
     */
    private $collection;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: nice it's works ! I tried this solution through validation.yml, maybe I did not write something right .. for tooltip  (like required => true) i have to use Js ?

Comment: I'm not sure `'required' => true` works for a set of checkboxes. It's likely you'll need JS validation for that.